# Resteasy - Login from C#

Tags: resteasy

I have a Resteasy service that I need to call from a C# application; what's the best way of securing the content I want to get from the service?
I was looking for a tutorial cause I'm not familiar with web services in Java, but I couldn't find anything...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use HTTPS and basic authentication

Comment: @eiden Thank for the answer, do you mean something like that:

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/Securing_JAX-RS_and_RESTeasy.html ?

If yes, how can I provide passwords for the web roles?

Thank you again!